# (17.10) I've turned off automatic screen locking, but there's still an annoying "lock" screen to click through

Tags: 17.10, lock-screen

I've found the settings for automatic locking and turned it off. This has worked in that I no longer need to enter my password when waking the computer. But there's still a big orange screen in the way which I need to click through or hit escape to dismiss before I can actually see the desktop. Can this be disabled at all?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen 'true'
```

If it doesn't work, then use [dconf-tools](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/dconf-tools) and use dconf-editor to set the same setting manually.

Comment: Sadly not... I tried both dconf-tools and `gsettings` and there's still a pointless screen to click though. Thanks for trying.